# How to detect when user have scrolled to the top most item in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have tried writing the following code

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
  super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
  if(dy > 0){
    //scrolling up
  } else {
    //scrolling down
    int pastVisibleItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if (pastVisibleItems  == 0) {
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Top most item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have also tried using the android's SwipeRefreshLayout to do this since it does what I want which is able to detect when user has scroll to the topmost item. I decided to not use it because I can't seem to prevent the loading indicator from popping out (I don't want to see the loading indicator come out at all).

So, basically what I want to do is:

1. check user scrolling
2. is it the topmost item already?
3. if yes, execute something, if no then nothing

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved my question by myself. I used the code below instead

```
private boolean isUserScrolling = false;
private boolean isListGoingUp = true;
```

Then in the RecyclerView OnScrollListener

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    //detect is the topmost item visible and is user scrolling? if true then only execute
    if(newState ==  RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
        isUserScrolling = true;
        if(isListGoingUp){
            //my recycler view is actually inverted so I have to write this condition instead
            if(linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1 == list.size()){
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(isListGoingUp) {
                            if (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1 == list.size()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"exeute something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },50);
                //waiting for 50ms because when scrolling down from top, the variable isListGoingUp is still true until the onScrolled method is executed
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if(isUserScrolling){
        if(dy > 0){
            //means user finger is moving up but the list is going down
            isListGoingUp = false;
        }
        else{
            //means user finger is moving down but the list is going up
            isListGoingUp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace your code with below code:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
  super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

  int pastVisibleItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
  if (pastVisibleItems  == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Top most item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
  }
}
```

it works for me, if you get any error then comment.

Comment: actually my list is inverted

i used this code instead
if (pastVisibleItems+1  == historyList.size())
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Top most item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but my pastVisibleItems is getting 244, while the list is actually 250

Comment: @carlos what is your pastVisibleItems ? which value store in that var

Comment: umm, some thing to note is that 1) my list.size() will return 250. 2) my RecyclerView has been set to Reverse meaning the top most item's position should be 249. 3) the RecyclerView can only show 7 items at once due to screen size. 4) When i am scrolling to the topmost, the pastVisibleItems is returning 244 only. So it is not working...

Comment: this approach is not working if your items are larger than your screen.. this way 'findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()' always returns -1

Comment: yes than try findFirstVisibleItemPosition() this function may be this will work
@Katharina

Comment: for me this is worked.
 linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

Comment: great @Rameshbabu Thanks for comment and is possible pls upVote

Answer (score 4):

You Can Do  This easily use Code

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if(newState ==  RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            isUserScrolling = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if(isUserScrolling){
            if(dy > 0){
               //Scroll list Down
            }
            else{
                if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)){

                  //This Your Top View do Something
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```