# "Shrink" CardView while scrolling in another view

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Screenshot

[image]

As you can see, the layout is a bit too big for the older device. My idea is to shrink the CardView while the user is scrolling in the white area (ViewPager) to make it bigger. I have seen it working well in another app (can't remember which). I have no idea how I can do it, do I need write it programmatically?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WordActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_dark"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wordTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/poweredBy"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:text="@string/word_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wordTranslated"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/wordTitle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/wordTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/bungee_hairline"
                android:text="@string/powered"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardView">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white_transparent" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try again with this sample layout.

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bckg_toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#202020"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FBA601"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FBA601"
                    app:tabTextColor="#fff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

scene 1

[image]

scene 2

[image]

Comment: **Almost!** It's working, exactly in the way you wanted it, but I want the collapsing area to be collapsed all the way up, not halfway like in your codes. How can I change?

One more thing, I'd want the content to collapse while the user is scrolling in the ViewPager, but it's ok if you don't know.

Comment: **I've solved it**, I needed to change in the scrollFlags to "scroll". I mark your answer as it helped me with my problem, thank you very much! Really appreciated. I also figured out how to solve my second problem in the comment above, it was to wrap the ViewPager with NestedScrollView.

Comment: i'm gleeful that i helped with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be applicable to your current layout but if you can integrate Android's [collapsing toolbars](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) you may save youself a bit of time.

Otherwise you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847534/how-to-detect-when-user-have-scrolled-to-the-top-most-item-in-a-recyclerview) to detect when the user is at the top of your list and show the view, hiding it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample layout, just change the code inside nested scrollview with your tablayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bckg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/textLoremIpsum"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my sample screenshot

Scene 1

[image]

Scene 2

[image]

Comment: Can you please show how I can implement it into my XML? I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: okay i just post another answer here, so my previous answer can guide other people with this kind of layout also.